# How to disable account on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, user-account, login, accounts

I have an account on my OS X Mavericks system that I want to disable so it cannot be used for login. I would not like to delete the account permanently but rather disable it temporarily.

I believe that this was possible in Lion – but maybe my memory plays tricks on me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can disable a user account by setting their shell to **/usr/bin/false**.

Either run `chsh -s /usr/bin/false <username>`, or change it in Users & Groups → Advanced Options. To change it back, run `chsh -s /bin/bash <username>`.

Comment: I was aware of this trick, but does it also apply to GUI logins?

Comment: @mgd Yes it does :)

Comment: I just used this, and now (after re-enabling the account, which was an admin, btw) the account can't use the Terminal: `login: /etc/shells: Permission denied`.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: This doesn't work any more on Mac OS X 10.13 High Sierra. You're still able to login via the Login Window

Answer (score 15):

Changing the login shell does not stop the GUI login, but does stop shell / ssh login.

The answer is given by:
https://serverfault.com/questions/61214/how-can-i-disable-a-user-account-from-the-cli-with-mac-os-x-server#new-answer

With details on hiding given by: 
https://support.apple.com/en-au/ht203998

pwpolicy can both disable and enable users, without losing their password

To disable the user

```
pwpolicy -u username disableuser
```

To enable the user

```
pwpolicy -u username enableuser
```

Use dscl to hide the user so they don't show on login:

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/username IsHidden 1
```

To show a hidden user

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/username IsHidden 0
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked on regular accounts. But can this also work on service accounts?

Comment: Sorry, don’t have a server to test it on. The account disabled marks the account as disabled in the password database. Should work on all macs using OSX

Answer (score 5):

For Yosemite and newer, you can use

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/UserName IsHidden 1
```

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203998

Comment: This doesn't actually disable the account, it just hides the username on the login page. There's still an 'Others' entry there where the hidden user can enter their username and password.