# error: login: /bin/false: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, mojave

I get a new Mac but the terminal doesn't work. Is there anyone met this situation before? When I open terminal, it shows below error:

```
Last login: Mon Sep 23 14:12:13 on ttys000
login: /bin/false: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
  [Restored Sep 23, 2019 at 2:16:08 PM]
Last login: Mon Sep 23 14:16:04 on console
login: /bin/false: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `echo "$SHELL"` outputs `bin/bash` in mine. A mod at [FreeBSD](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/bin-false-no-such-file-or-directory.54084/) says "Boot to single user mode and fix root's shell". So I guess that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed issue by selecting the bash I want to use:

System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Advanced

Comment: [how-to-disable-account-on-os-x-mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135184/how-to-disable-account-on-os-x-mavericks/135185#135185) See this too!